# Eagle Change Isolation of all Polygons

Tags: eaglecad

I drew my pcb in eagle with polygons' isolation is set to 0(default) but I need to change it to 0.35mm. I have lots of polygons, doing it manually is too hard. Is there a way to change all polygon's isolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally do not know a way of globally changing polygon's isolation but a method I would use to make it quicker is to type in the command bar: 'Change isolate '0.35mm'' and then you can easily click on each polygon and it is much quicker than manually right clicking and changing properties.

I have just found out that **the isolate parameter is only applicable to polygons**. So to do it more quickly you can 'group' your entire PCB board and using the same command as above (or going through the tool bar menu) right-click and select change group - this will apply the change to all of your polygons without having to click many times!

Comment: Great idea, but I don't think typing the command applies to the selected group. I think you have to click the change tool, select the isolate value, right-click on the screen, and then click on "Change: Group". I'm giving a +1 with the assumption you'll update your answer after you see this.

Comment: I'm marking as answered with the assumption you'll update your answer after you see Dan's comment. thank you so much guys.

Comment: @DanLaks You can type the command and then do the right click process, this is what I mean in my answer.